# Redirect to mobile version of page: TYPO3

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, typo3, typoscript

I have a TYPO3 site with a mobile version (m.example.com), so its not responsive, and I have one problem I need to solve real soon.

For example when I enter example.com/kontakt, it always redirect me to m.example.com, and this is normal because i set up my typoscript like this:

```
[useragent = *iPhone*] && [globalString = IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY = www.example.com]
config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://m.example.com/
[global]
[useragent = *Android*] && [globalString = IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY = www.example.com]
config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://m.example.com/
[global]
```

Is there any way to setup redirection with paramters to mobile version of desired page in typoscript or in the .htaccess file?

So when I enter example.com/kontakt on my mobile device to open m.example.com/kontakt page.

Thank you very much in advance guys. :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you already check out extensions like cwmobileredirect for your purposes? https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cwmobileredirect/ExtMobileRedirect/Index.html

Comment: Hi Paul, 

No, thank you very much, although my version of Typo3 is 4.7, so i will need to try with older version.

Comment: This extension is what I needed, thank you very much Paul :)